# Itertools to speed up nested loops in beautiful soup

Tags: python, python-3.x, beautifulsoup, nested-loops, python-itertools

This is the code written in Python 3 and it works. But running it with four nested loops and more inside it's super slow.

How can I implement itertools to speed up the loops a bit?

For 25 rows with 4 columns of data this takes around 20 seconds.

```
import bs4 as bs
import urllib.request
import time

start_time = time.time()

a=[]
b=[]
c=[]
d=[]

for z in range(1,10):
    source = urllib.request.urlopen(f'https://X.com/id={z}').read()
    soup = bs.BeautifulSoup(source,'html.parser')

    for i in range(0,50):
        for name in soup.find_all('span',id=f"tblRightHolders:{i}:cellRHSurnameName"):
            a.insert(i,name.string)
        for city in soup.find_all('span',id=f"tblRightHolders:{i}:cellRHPlace"):
            b.insert(i,city.string)
        for street in soup.find_all('span', id=f"tblRightHolders:{i}:cellRHStreet"):
            c.insert(i,street.string)
        for number in soup.find_all('span', id=f"tblRightHolders:{i}:cellRHNumber"):
            d.insert(i,number.string)
    
X = [list(e) for e in zip(a, b, c, d)]
for nested in X:
    print(" - ".join(map(str, nested)))

print("--- %s seconds ---" % (time.time() - start_time))
```

The data get's output like this:

`Name/Surname - City - Street - Street number`

Comment: @superbrain: Look at the `id` parameter.

Comment: I suspect almost all time is spent in downloading the pages or in `soup.find_all`, which `itertools` won't help with at all.

Answer (score 1):

I do not think that `itertools` will speed it up - they can just provide nicer approach for more readable code.   If you want to speed it up, there are several options:

1. Use [joblib](https://joblib.readthedocs.io/en/latest/parallel.html) for parallelization
2. Try using some just-in-time compiler such as [numba](http://numba.pydata.org/) but for that you would have to probably rewrite the code as the soup code won't most likely be complient with numba
3. rewrite the critical code in C/C++, rust or cython

Those last two are most likely overkills. Go with simple parallelism using joblib if you can (i.e., have multiple cores available). Itertools won't help you with speeding it up, they can just make your code nicer.

[edit]
I do recommend timing your code first. If your code spends most of the time with downloading the pages, you can just go with joblib but using  threads instead of processes. I was just today doing something similar with 100 separate threads for webpage requests.

Comment: But doesn't this require multiple CPU's/processors from a hardware perspective? (Just curious, I guess the OP will run the script on a multiprocessor machine anyways)

Comment: @Jonas It requires to have multiple CPU cores (as written in the last paragraph). That is usually the case for most users that are not running on virtual machines or some embedded devices. Multiple CPUs are a bit more complicated usually, but they do usually behave as a single multicore CPU so it should work the same usually. If he has only single core available and needs to speed it up, I would go for rust or some similar language and wrote a python extension to be called from rust using https://github.com/PyO3/pyo3.

Comment: Thanks for the insights